# how to determine weak and strong entity in ER model

Tags: mysql, database-design, er-modeling

ER modeling below situation

" a car insurance company whose customers
own one or more cars each. Each car has associated with it zero to any
number of recorded accidents. Each insurance policy covers one or more
cars, and has one or more premium payments associated with it. Each
payment is for a particular period of time, and has an associated due date,
and the date when the payment was received"

[the answer ER model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AQpD.png)

Above situation, First, I think 'car' is participated partially and 'accident' is participated totally. But the answer image is reversed.
Also, I don't know WHY 'car' and 'accident' is not identifying relationship. I think accident is dependent on car.

Answer (score 0):

To heck with terminology; let's think about the data:

1. Each Entity needs a table:  Customers, Cars, Accidents, Policies, Premiums
2. Determine the Relations, and whether they are 1:many or many:many
3. Build a many:many table for each such Relation.  (In some situations, extra data can be put in that table.)  (You don't have such?)

Not needed: Customers (1:many) Cars -- because of Customers->Policys->Cars
Cars (1:many) Accidents (allowing zero takes no extra effort)
Customers (1:many??) Policies
Policies (1:many) Cars
Policies (1:many) Payments

4. For the 1:many Relations, have the id of the "1" in the "many" table.  Eg, PolicyId should be a column in the tables Cars and Payments.

Comment: but if you see the 'answer ER model', car and policy are not identifying relationship.
the only idetifying relationship is payment. I don't know why

Comment: I see "payment" as an Entity.